# Group python tuple by first item

Tags: python

I have the following long python tuple:

```
('user1', 'data1', 'name1'), ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'), ('user1', 'data2', 'name2'), ('user2', 'data2', 'name2') etc..
```

I would like to group the tuple as follows

```
('user1', 'data1', 'name1', name2 ), ('user2', 'data1', 'name1', name2) etc..
```

Would anyone know how to do this.. thus far I have :

```
from itertools import groupby

things = [('user1', 'data1', 'name1'), ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'), ('user1', 'data2', 'name2'), ('user2', 'data2', 'name2')]

things =  sorted(things, key=lambda tup: tup[0])

for key, group in groupby(things, lambda x: x[0]):
    print key
    for thing in group:
        print (key, thing[1], things[2])
    print " "
```

Which outputs

```
user1
('user1', 'data1', ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'))
('user1', 'data2', ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'))

user2
('user2', 'data1', ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'))
('user2', 'data2', ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'))
```

However this does not group the third item 'name' correctly...

Comment: Syntax error? Maybe you want `print (key, thing[1], thing[2])`.  Also, to be explicit, you could insert `from itertools import groupby` at the top of your code.

Comment: If you want to group by the first element of the tuple, why doesn't `data2` show up in the resulting tuple starting with `user1`? Is this intented?

Comment: Couldn't `print (key, thing[1], things[2])` be replaced by `print thing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the 8th line of the code you pasted, where you are indexing `things` rather than `thing`. Instead of

```
print (key, thing[1], things[2])
```

you want

```
print (key, thing[1], thing[2])
```

Then you will get the output you're expecting.

Note: @wildwilhelm pointed this out first in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a nice place to use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

```
from collections import defaultdict

things = [('user1', 'data1', 'name1'), 
          ('user2', 'data1', 'name1'), 
          ('user1', 'data2', 'name2'), 
          ('user2', 'data2', 'name2')]

grouped_things = defaultdict(list)
for thing in things:
    grouped_things[thing[0]].append(thing)
for key in grouped_things:
    print key
    for thing in grouped_things[key]:
        print thing
    print
```

Results:

```
user2
('user2', 'data1', 'name1')
('user2', 'data2', 'name2')

user1
('user1', 'data1', 'name1')
('user1', 'data2', 'name2')
```

Comment: Good solution, never heard of `defaultdict`, a nice thing :)